# Zip only public directory

Tags: linux, zip, console, tar

I've a lot of websites (100+ directories) I want to create a unique zip with only public subdirectory.

My structure now is like:

```
- Site 1
--- app
--- tmp
--- log
--- public

- Site 2
--- app
--- tmp
--- log
--- public

- ... 100+ dirs ...
```

Now I need a unique zip and then after unzip it I want to see this structure:

```
- Site 1
--- public

- Site 2
--- public

- others
```

Any suggestion how I can do that with linux commands zip/tar ?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think this is probably a better fit for http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Just use wildcards to only specify the public directories:

```
zip file.zip -r */public
```

Comment: There is a same version with tar? With zip I've file size limit 4gb. Thanks!

Comment: Basically I got: zip error: Input file read failure but If I try to zip only the file with error works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sites/ $ ls

Site 1
Site 2
...
Site 100

$ zip sites.zip * -r -x app tmp log
```

Comment: can be quite slow

Answer (score 0):

As you have 'tar' tagged. You could try

```
tar cvjf /path/to/save/at/archive.tar.bz2 . --exclude='*/app' --exclude='*/tmp' --exclude='*/log'
```

to create a bz2 archive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` to generate the list:

```
find . -type d -name public -print > list.txt
tar -cvf test.tar -T list.txt
```

Comment: Im trying this, I hope with tar there isn't any size limit.